# Using COUNT() and MIN() between two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

**Class**

```
class_id (pk)
class_name
```

**Student**

```
student_Id (pk)
class_id (fk)
student_name
```

I am trying to get the class name with minimum number of students enrolled. For that i have  am trying with the following code bust it says alias error.

```
SELECT class_name, COUNT(student_id) as total_students
FROM class, student
WHERE total_students = MIN(total_students)
  AND class.class_id = student.class_id
GROUP BY student.class_id;
```

Can someone help me find the error?

Comment: Try again.  You cannot use `MIN()` in the `WHERE` clause.  Your query should use `JOIN`, not commas in the `FROM` clause.  You should also learn to use table aliases.  I would suggest you try some more attempts.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit` clause as follows:

```
SELECT class_name, COUNT(student_id) as total_students
FROM class c join student s on c.class_id=s.class_id
GROUP BY student.class_id
Order by COUNT(student_id)
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code is tested with oracle 11g SQL developer.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            class_name,
            COUNT(student_id)
        FROM
            class      c
            JOIN student1   s ON c.class_id = s.class_id
        GROUP BY
            class_name
        ORDER BY
            2
    )
WHERE
    ROWNUM = 1;
```

Here I improved my code with another outer query to retrieve the first row the min()  with the  "WHERE ROWNUM = 1 " clause

But be careful to use it correctly after the FROM clause
This is the reason the outer Select exist.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, aggregate and use `RANK()` window function to get the classes with the min count:

```
SELECT class_name, total_students
FROM (
  SELECT c.class_name, COUNT(*) total_students,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) rnk
  FROM class c INNER JOIN student s
  ON s.class_id = c.class_id
  GROUP BY c.class_id, c.class_name
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First,there is a syntax error by using GROUP BY, YOu have to include the column from your select list (except the one u are using with the aggregate function)inside your group by.

Try this code with oracle sql developer

```
WITH student_cnt AS
(
    SELECT class_id, COUNT(student_id)  cnt 
    FROM student1 
    GROUP BY class_id
)
SELECT class_name, MIN(cnt)
FROM class,student_cnt
WHERE class.class_id = student_cnt.class_id
GROUP BY class_name;
```

It should give you the class name with the count.

The following code is written with ORACLE SQL developer
Here you can not reference column alias elsewhere except in the ORDER BY clause;

Select class_name, count(student_id) cnt_student
From class c join student1 s
On c.class_id = s.class_id
Group by class_name
Order by cnt_student;

Be careful with the use of column alias.
The rules are from oracle sql by the way I don't know if it is the same elsewhere.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: BUT IT IS TESTED WITH GIVEING THE RIGHT RESULT SETS. you can replace it with the on clause of course  ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

tested with a simple table/ but I don't know how to retrieve only the first record which is the minimum class_name and its count.

Comment: You can edit your 1st answer with this code. There is no need to post a 2nd answer.